# Verifying if a void method has been called using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a class which is responsible for building PPT slides for exporting. To unit test this I have created an interface so it can be mocking using Moq; all great so far. However I run into difficulties when trying to test that my method has been called. It is a void method so at this point I only want to know that the method has been hit.

Here is my interface:

```
interface IPowerpointExporter
{
    void AddSlides(int amount);

    void setTitle(string title);
}
```

And here's my unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void testPPTObject()
{
    var mockPPT = new Mock<IPowerpointExporter>();
    mockPPT.Setup(m => m.AddSlides(1)).Verifiable();
    mockPPT.Object.AddSlides(1);
    mockPPT.VerifyAll();
}
```

However when I come to call `AddSlides()` I get a `GeneratorException`. The explanation for this is that my IPowerpointExporter was not accessible. I have a feeling this is because I am trying to call a method on an interface, though I'm unsure since I've got my object at `mockPPT.Object.AddSlides();` at this point.

Note that I've also tried the following trying to use an actual object rather than Interface.Object. This also gives the same exception:

```
[TestMethod]
public void testPPTObject()
{
    var mockPPT = new Mock<IPowerpointExporter>();
    mockPPT.Setup(m => m.AddSlides(1)).Verifiable();

    ExportPowerPoint temp = (ExportPowerPoint)mockPPT.Object;
    temp.AddSlides(1);
    mockPPT.VerifyAll();
}
```

Using Moq how can I check that my method has been called? Is what I'm doing above along the right lines?

Comment: It seems that you are testing your mock. You should test the code using IPowerpointExporter, and there verify that the method on the (mocked) interface is called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're likely getting that exception because your interface is not `public`, or otherwise visible to the Moq assembly.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28234369/1698557) to resolve that.

If this is just dummy code to help you learn Moq, then read no further.

---

However, if this an actual test that you think has value, then you have other more fundamental issues. In your first example, **you're doing absolutely nothing to test your code!**  Let's go through it, line by line:

```
var mockPPT = new Mock<IPowerpointExporter>();
```

You created a mock of your `IPowerpointExporter` interface, so far so good.

```
mockPPT.Setup(m => m.AddSlides(1)).Verifiable();
```

You told the mock to expect a call to it's `AddSlide` method, with an argument of `1`, and that the method can be verified.  No problem so far.

```
mockPPT.Object.AddSlides(1);
```

But here's where it goes off the rails.  You're just invoking the method on your mock, the same one you just setup above.  The `Object` property is a *dummy object*, it can only do what it was setup to do and *has no ties to your actual implementation*!

```
mockPPT.VerifyAll();
```

Now you verified that you called all your verifiable methods.  All you did in this test was verify that Moq works; your code was never touched.

Let's look at the changed code in your second example now:

```
ExportPowerPoint temp = (ExportPowerPoint)mockPPT.Object;
temp.AddSlides(1);
```

*That cast will never work.*  The `Object` property is just some proxy (a dynamic type actually), generated by Moq that knows nothing about any concrete implementation of the interface it is mocking.

Comment: To get myself back on the right track how can I test that the method call has been hit? Would simply creating an ExportPowerPoint object and call the AddSlides() method on it be enough to trigger the VerifyAll()?

Comment: Your first example will do what you want (if you fix the visibility of your interface), but as I said it's a worthless test for anything other than learning Moq.

Answer (score 1):

This exception occurs because `IPowerpointExporter` interface is not accessible to Moq.

You can make your `IPowerpointExporter` interface `public`, and test runs perfectly:

```
public interface IPowerpointExporter
{
    void AddSlides(int amount);

    void setTitle(string title);
}

....

[TestMethod]
public void testPPTObject()
{
    var mockPPT = new Mock<IPowerpointExporter>();
    mockPPT.Setup(m => m.AddSlides(1)).Verifiable();

    ExportPowerPoint temp = (ExportPowerPoint)mockPPT.Object;
    temp.AddSlides(1);
    mockPPT.VerifyAll();
}
```

However, when you need make tests to non-public types, you can use `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute in your assembly to make types visible to Moq.

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]
```