# How to mark a C# assembly as a CLS Compliant when using new csproj format?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I recently upgraded a C# project from `xproj` format to the new `csproj`. During the migration, the old `AssemblyInfo.cs` has been removed so I'm wondering how I can indicate that my library is clscompliant?

FYI: this is the attribute that was in the AssemblyInfo.cs:

`[assembly:CLSCompliant(true)]`

Comment: It does not matter in what source file this attribute appears, put it anywhere.  Time to retire it btw, it has not been useful for a decade.

Comment: @HansPassant a user told me this attribute was necessary so he could use my C# library in his VB.NET app.

Comment: It this was an SO user then post a link so we can vote/answer.  If not then it is up to you to make him smarter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add `AssemblyInfo.cs` back, with only the parts that aren't autogenerated.

There's nothing to stop you from applying assembly attributes in code - it's just that most of the common attributes are provided from the project settings.

Comment: Why it's not possible like for **InternalsVisibleTo** (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42810705/visual-studio-2017-and-the-new-csproj-internalsvisibleto)? I've tried, but it fails because `true` is parsed as a string. What's the correct form of **boolean literal** in a csproj file (MSBuild)?

Comment: @gsscoder: Please ask a new question - it's not at all clear to me what you've got at the moment.

Comment: Hi @Jon Skeet, thanks for replying! This is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927051/mark-an-assembly-clscompliant-in-csproj.